# Create a B object from selected A objects using Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I'm beginner in Django. I want to create some ERP from Django Admin.

My problem is I have some functions that need to select objects from another **model A** before create a new **model B** using the selected objects from that **model A** (the relation is many-to-one)

**Example**
I have **model A** and **model B**.
Let's say I want to create **model B**. I must go to the **model A**'s list to select objects (either check or select) then I submit the list to create **model B**. After that, redirect (or use another way) to a page which used for create **model B** that include all objects I selected from **model A**. When submit, it will save and create **model B**'s object that have many **model A**'s objects.

I have to select **model A**'s objects from the list, not by search from the inline form.

I have tried several ways but not succeed.

This is my code (some code I got from Django Documentation and `django/contrib/admin/options.py` in the `changform_views` method)

The flow is when I select **model A**'s objects and select action `pass_cheque` then it will redirect to a view which use to create **model B** (the problem is I can't get `ModelAdmin` from my `views (B)` to create admin form).

**admin.py**

```
def pass_receive_cheque(modeladmin, request, queryset):
   selected = request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)
   ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(queryset.model)
   return HttpResponseRedirect("/passcheque/receive/?ct=%s&ids=%s" % (ct.pk,",".join(selected)))
```

**views.py**

```
def pass_receive_cheque(request):
   modeladmin = ??? #I don't know what i should do
   opts = modeladmin.model._meta
   app_label = opts.app_label
   obj = None
   add = True
   ModelForm = modeladmin.get_form(request, obj)
   initial = modeladmin.get_changeform_initial_data(request)
   form = ModelForm(initial=initial)
   formsets, inline_instances = modeladmin._create_formsets(request, modeladmin.model(), change=False)
   adminForm = helpers.AdminForm(
      form,
      list(modeladmin.get_fieldsets(request, obj)),
      modeladmin.get_prepopulated_fields(request, obj),
      modeladmin.get_readonly_fields(request, obj),
      model_admin=modeladmin)
   media = modeladmin.media + adminForm.media
   inline_formsets = modeladmin.get_inline_formsets(request, formsets, inline_instances, obj)
   for inline_formset in inline_formsets:
       media = media + inline_formset.media
   return render(request, 'account_statement/passcheque.html', {
       'title': 'PASS CHEQUE',
       'site_header': 'HSL FINANCE',
       'opts': opts,
       'change': False,
       'is_popup': False,
       'save_as': True,
       'has_delete_permission': False,
       'has_add_permission': True,
       'has_change_permission': True,
       'add': add,
       'adminform': adminForm,
       'media': media,
       'inline_admin_formsets': inline_formsets,
       'errors': helpers.AdminErrorList(form, formsets),
   })
```

Thank you for every answers and suggestions.

Comment: Can you post your model.py?

Comment: @ger.s.brett this is my models.py http://pastebin.com/vy5Qt0Hy

model A is ReceiveCheque
model B is ReceiveChequeRecord

Comment: Why is your cheque_record a ForeignKey field? It should be a ManyToMany field. If you change this you will have a field in the admin where you can select several ReceiveChequeRecord instances for each ReceiveCheque instance. Is this what you want to do?